# how can i make a percentage bar for an int 0-100in c# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, percentage, windows-forms-designer

```
int Score = 0;         //Amount of wins
int Fouls = 0;         //Amount of wrongs
int percentage = 0;    //Win percentage
if (Win == true)
{
    Score ++;          //Score is printed 
}
if (Wrong = true)
{
    Fouls ++;          //Fouls are printed
}
// How can i make a percentege bar for "Percentage"
percentage = (((Score) * 100) / (Score + Fouls));
```

the percentage bar is just a rectangle with green and red rechangles, and a white number of the percentage.

Comment: What is the problem you have? Is it the percentage *progress* bar itself? Or the calculation?

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.